# Passing a signed byte array through a BluetoothSocket in Monodroid

Tags: c#, java, xamarin.android

I am having an interesting problem using Monodroid to send commands to a device via Bluetooth.

I am using this Monodroid method:

BluetoothSocket.OutputStream.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);

I need to send the following 8-byte frame:

- 0x51
- 0x26
- 0x0
- 0x0
- 0x0
- 0x0
- 0xFFFFFFA3
- 0x0

The problem is that 0xFFFFFFA3 is a signed byte (-93) so this means I need to use C#.NET's sbyte rather than byte to create the array to pass to the Write method.

However, I cannot pass an sbyte[] array to the Write method I can only pass a byte[] array.  C#.NET does not allow me to put 0xFFFFFFA3 in a byte because it is signed.

What can I do to pass the command through the socket?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0xFFFFFFA3 is the size of an Int32, which may be why the compiler is complaining.  You should be able to just specify a byte value of 0xA3.